# Customizing local paging default size for a single controller method with the default values defined in the application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, pagination

If no query parameters (page & size) are given, I'm trying to set the `Pageable` object value and populated with the default values defined in the `application.properties`. If query parameters are given, `Pageable` object is populated with the value of the query parameter.

application.properties

```
post.page.maxSize=2
```

RestController

```
@Value("${post.page.maxSize}") private int maxSize;
```

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/list"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
        public ModelAndView list(
                @AuthenticationPrincipal LoginUser loginUser, 
                ModelAndView mav, 
                @ModelAttribute("form") Form form, 
                Locale locale,
                @PageableDefault(size = maxSize, page = 0) Pageable pageable,
                HttpServletRequest request
                ){
            
            
                Page<ListEntity> page = service.searchList(form, pageable);
    
                PageWrapper<ListEntity> pageWrapper = new PageWrapper<ListEntity>(page, url);
                
                mav.addObject("form", form);
                mav.addObject("page", pageWrapper);
            
            return mav;
        }
```

Above code `@PageableDefault(size = maxSize)` will not work as the value for annotation attribute PageableDefault.size must be a constant expression. And in my case `spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size` setting isn't relevant because my problem is not about global paging.
Any Suggestions would help :)